# Display Tagline if Tagline Exists - Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'd like to echo out a few lines of HTML as well as my tagline if the tagline exists. I'm not sure how to check if a tagline exists.

Here is where I'm up to:

```
<?php if (bloginfo('description')) 
    echo '<div class="tagline-message"><div><h3>
          <?php bloginfo("description"); ?>
          </div></div></h3>'
?>
```

This doesn't work as saying bloginfo('description') in the if condition is not the correct usage of bloginfo()

How do I check if a tagline exists?

Thanks!
- Mikey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [`get_bloginfo()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) (you need to `return` the value to the conditional, rather than print/echo it):

```
<?php 
    $description = get_bloginfo('description');

    if ( $description ) {
        echo '<div class="tagline-message"><div><h3>' . $description . '</div></div></h3>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Yes this works perfectly, 4mins till I can accept the answer! You Rule!

Comment: Thanks. Make sure to take note of the way I've "concatenated" the strings together. You had some invalid quotes in your original code.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `get_option` method to determine if a setting exists. It will return `false` if no value exists for the setting. Note that `blogdescription` is the setting name for Tag Line.

```
<? php if (get_option('blogdescription')) 
    echo '<div class="tagline-message"><div><h3>
          <?php bloginfo('description'); ?>
          </div></div></h3>'
?>
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

Comment: Thanks Steve! I have noticed another issue which is that 'description' becomes unexpected due to it's "   '   " apostrophe cancelling the string. any way around this?

Comment: You should be able to prefix the apostrophes with a backslash: `<?php bloginfo(\'description\'); ?>`